# & printing out the rest of a string instead of the address

Tags: c++, pointers

Keep in mind that my knowledge of pointers is quite small, as I just started learning about them.

While I was messing around in C++, I wrote this small bit of code thinking it would just print out the address of each character in the string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string a = "Hello, World!";

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<a.length();i++) {
        cout << &a[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran this, however, it resulted in it printing as if the string moved to the left.[image]

It just doesn't make sense why when it uses &, which I thought would retrieve the address, would instead get the rest of the string.

Comment: `&a[i]` is a pointer to a char. There is a specific overload to handle that, which is to print a null terminated string. If you want the address you need to cast the pointer to (void*).

Comment: Cast to `void *` to avoid

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comment, `&a[i]` is a pointer to a `char`, and `<<` operator will print null terminated string starting from this character, not its address. So if you want to print the address, you must cast it to `void *`, as follow :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string a = "Hello, World!";

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<a.length();i++) {
        cout << (void *)&a[i] << endl; //cast to (void *) to get the address
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user463035818, yes you're right. Thanks for helping me to make this answer more accurate

Comment: fine with me, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

`string` subscript (`[]`) operator returns `char`. So `&` operation returns a pointer to `char`. And `cout` `operator<<` has an overloading for it, which consider it should print out the parameter as a c-string. You should cast it to `void*` so `cout` wouldn't think it is a string.

```
(void*)&a[i]
```